# Typing the semidirect product symbol

Tags: symbols

I am using writelatex to write a paper and I need to type the semidirect product symbol...but for some reason, it keeps saying "error" and I can't see the semidirect product in the paper. I tried both `\rtimes` and `\ltimes` and both did not work. I searched the internet to see if there were other ways to type it using latex but I only found these two, and they both didn't work in writelatex...so I was wondering if anybody could help me with this...

Comment: Are you using the amssymb package?

Comment: And here goes a MWE: https://www.writelatex.com/158819zfcjtc

Comment: @kan I was using amsmath. So do I have to change it to amsyymb?

Comment: No, I'd think you'll have to load `amsmath` together with `amssymb`: `\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}`.

Comment: The ams packages are distributed in several different families. Take a look at ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf and ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsfonts/amsfndoc.pdf to see what the `amsmath` and `amssymb` packages contain.

Comment: @Artus `amsmath` provides many facilities for typesetting, such as alignment environments; `amssymb` provides scores of symbols; they are complementary, not alternative.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use [DeTeXify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) for finding out such things:

[image]

It also tells you that you need the `amssymb` package.